# Retrieve multiple `td` values with the same `Class` name using HTMLAgilityPack Library .NET

Tags: html, .net, winforms, html-agility-pack

I just got to use HTMLAgilityPack again and I'm really running out of ideas why my code executes this way. So I have this HTML code. This is just an experiment HTML code to make it easier for experimentation.

```
<html>
<tbody class="person">
<div class="name">Chris</div>
<td class="num">3,200</td>
<td class="num">62,000</td>
<td class="num">59,700</td>
<td class="num">1,500</td>
</tbody>

<tbody class="person">
<div class="name">John</div>
<td class="num">23,200</td>
<td class="num">900</td>
<td class="num">60,100</td>
<td class="num">1,300</td>
</tbody>

<tbody class="person">
<div class="name">James</div>
<td class="num">900</td>
<td class="num">60</td>
<td class="num">61,400</td>
<td class="num">610</td>
</tbody>
</html>
```

My current code so far is this...

```
Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("C:/sample.html")
For Each tbody As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody[contains(@class, 'person')]")
    Dim numberNode = tbody.SelectSingleNode("//tbody[contains(@class, 'person')]")
    Dim valueNode = numberNode.SelectNodes(".//td[contains(@class, 'num')]")
    Dim numbers As String()
    numbers = (From n In valueNode Select n.InnerText).ToArray()
    Dim nameNode As HtmlNode = tbody.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'name')]")
    If nameNode IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(numbers(0) & " " & numbers(1) & " " & numbers(2) & " " & numbers(3) & " - " & nameNode.InnerText, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "System Message")
    End If
Next
```

I'm really confused why it's only returning the first number values. The number values don't correspond to the `<div class="name">`.

[image]

In my understanding, for every loop it does, it gets the corresponding data under each `<tbody class="person">`. How do I get the next number values that corresponds to the `<div class="name">`. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll juat say that is ugly HTML, not sure how much control you have over it. `div` shouldn't be a direct child of `tbody`, neither should `td` for that matter, they should be children of `tr`. Oh and I jest noticed the complete absence of `table` tags.

Comment: @Jon P, this isn't the real html code that I'll be using. Yes, it is ugly, but it's still valid html. I just created this quick to shorten the code to experiment. And this, however, is the format of the original professional website html that I'll be scraping. I just followed the format. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the mistake :

```
'select the first <tbody class="person"> element'
Dim numberNode = tbody.SelectSingleNode("//tbody[contains(@class, 'person')]")
'then get all <td class='num'> within above <tbody>'
Dim valueNode = numberNode.SelectNodes(".//td[contains(@class, 'num')]")
```

Try to change it to be as follow :

```
'get all <td class='num'> within <tbody> of current iteration'
Dim valueNode = tbody.SelectNodes(".//td[contains(@class, 'num')]")
```

Comment: Holy cow, it works! Now I understand. Thank you very very much. I appreciate it. Upvoted and marked your answer :)